# Compose functions which return Promises

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I would like to compose two functions which return Promises into a function which returns a Promise.

I really want to do this for asynchronous system calls, but to simplify things, for now I'm playing with Promises wrapped around setTimeout. Most of the system calls can be sent out and returned in any order, but in a few instances, data from one system call is needed to create a second system call.

In the enclosed example, I want to send out alerts with an interval of 5 seconds, then 3 seconds, then 10 seconds. When I run the code, things run in the wrong order.

I commented out code where I was able to run the two calls chained with ".then". The commented out code works as desired. But I haven't yet figured out how to put that into a function which returns a promise, and still have it work.

I'm interested in doing this using plain JavaScript only. After I understand how to do that, I'll look at answers which do the same using a library.

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dan_cron/g3d7e8tb/)

```
// Returns a Promise.
// I purposely chose not to use the callback function inside setTimeout in order to demonstrate
// how to combine functions which return Promises, and normal functions which don't.
function sleep(delay, callbackFunction) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, callbackFunction), delay)
  });
}

// Normal function, does not return a promise.
const myPrint = (message, value) => {
  alert(message + " " + value);
};

// A function combining a promise and then a normal function.
// Returns a Promise.
const sleepPrint = (delay) => {
  return sleep(delay)
    .then(() => {
      myPrint("sleepPrint()", delay);
    });
};

// A function combining two functions which return promises.
// Returns a Promise.
const sleepPrintSleepPrint = (delay1, delay2) => {
  return sleepPrint(delay1)
  .then(sleepPrint(delay2));
};

alert("Begin");
/*
// Run a Pomise function, then a normal function.
const delay = 4000;
sleep(delay)
.then(() => {
  myPrint("init", delay);
});
*/

const firstDelay = 5000;
const secondDelay = 3000;

/*
// Call sleepPrint() which runs a Promise function then a normal function.
// After all that finishes, call another Promise function, than another normal function.
// This code works as desired, but the code at the bottom doesn't!
sleepPrint(firstDelay)
.then(() => {
  return sleep(secondDelay)
})
.then(() => {
  myPrint("After sleepPrint() and sleep()", secondDelay);
});
*/

// Comine two calls to sleepPrint() into a new functiion which returns a Promise, sleepPrintsleepPrint().
// After all that finishes, call another Promise function, than another normal function.
// I want this to have 5 second delay and then a 3 second delay, but they are not running in that order.
const thirdDelay = 10000;
sleepPrintSleepPrint(firstDelay, secondDelay)
.then(() => {
  return sleep(thirdDelay)
})
.then(() => {
  myPrint("After sleepPrintSleepPrint()", thirdDelay);
});
```

Comment: Anonymous downvoter(s), please let me know what is wrong with this question, so I can improve my future questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember how functions work (in any programming language). This:

```
const sleepPrintSleepPrint = (delay1, delay2) => {
  return sleepPrint(delay1)
  .then(sleepPrint(delay2));
};
```

Is the same as this:

```
const sleepPrintSleepPrint = (delay1, delay2) => {
  var x = sleepPrint(delay2);
  return sleepPrint(delay1)
  .then(x);
};
```

What you are doing is calling both functions simultaneously. What I think you intend is to call the second function once then resolves. So you need to do this:

```
const sleepPrintSleepPrint = (delay1, delay2) => {
  return sleepPrint(delay1)
  .then(function(){return sleepPrint(delay2)});
};
```

Or if you prefer arrow function syntax:

```
const sleepPrintSleepPrint = (delay1, delay2) => {
  return sleepPrint(delay1)
  .then(() => sleepPrint(delay2));
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@slebetman supplied the correct code, and he explained the issue and the fix correctly at a high level. This is my understanding of his answer in more detail. This should be a comment to his answer, but it's too big.

The JavaScript interpreter makes two passes through code which contains chained ".then"s.

The first pass happens right away without any waiting. The interpreter looks at the argument(s) to .then, and does something different if it sees a function or an expression. Functions are placed onto the call stack, and associated with a promise. Expressions are evaluated, and if the completion value is a function, the function is placed onto the call stack, and associated with a promise.

In the second pass, after a promise has been resolved, the associated function from the call stack is evaluated.

In production code, chained .then's should always follow a specific pattern. The pattern is that the argument to ".then" is one function which returns a second callback function. In the first pass, nothing very interesting happens, the first function is executed, and the return value is the second callback function. The second callback function is placed onto the call stack and associated with a promise. In the second pass, after the associated promise has been resolved, the second callback function is executed.

But in this example, I am breaking the pattern in order to learn and demonstrate how chained .then's work.

Below is an example which does not use the pattern, and exposes the two pass behavior.

[This](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/then) is talking about the two arguments to .then, the success callback function, and the failure callback function.
"If one or both arguments are omitted or are provided non-functions, then then will be missing the handler(s), but will not generate any errors."

If you give a function to ".then", then in the first pass, the function is placed on the call stack, but nothing else happens, and in the second pass, the function is executed.
But if you give an expression to ".then", then in the first pass, the expression is evaluated. If the completion value is a function, it is placed onto the call stack, and executed in the second pass. If the completion value is not a function, in the second pass, no further action is taken, and no error is generated.

**First Pass** (The JavaScript interpreter runs these things immediateley.)

- Kick off sleepPrint(firstDelay). Let it run in the background.
- Immediately go to the next ".then".
- Print the first message. Put nothing on the call stack.
- Immediately go to the next ".then".
- Put the function () => sleepPrint(secondDelay) onto the call stack, and associate it with the preceding promise.
- Immediately go to the next ".then".
- Print the second message. Put nothing on the call stack.

**Second Pass** (The JavaScript interpreter runs each of these steps from the call stack much later, after the corresponding promise has been resolved.)

- Wait until sleepPrint(firstDelay) prints the third message, and is resolved, then go to the next item on the call stack.
- There's nothing on the call stack for this slot. There's no promise to resolve, so go to the next item on the call stack. No error is generated.
- Execute function () => sleepPrint(secondDelay) which prints the fourth message. Wait for the promise to be resolved, then go to the next item on the call stack.
- There's nothing on the call stack for this slot. There's no promise to resolve. No error is generated.

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dan_cron/2c09pcut/)

```
// Returns a Promise.
// I purposely chose not to use the callback function inside setTimeout in order to demonstrate
// how to combine functions which return Promises, and normal functions which don't.
function sleep(delay, callbackFunction) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve) {
    setTimeout(resolve.bind(null, callbackFunction), delay)
  });
}

// Normal function, does not return a promise.
const myPrint = (message, value) => {
  alert(message + " " + value);
};

// A function combining a promise and then a normal function.
// Returns a Promise.
const sleepPrint = (delay) => {
  return sleep(delay)
    .then(() => {
      myPrint("sleepPrint()", delay);
    });
};

alert("Begin");

const firstDelay = 5000;
const secondDelay = 3000;

// This message is printed third.
sleepPrint(firstDelay)
.then(
  myPrint("This message is printed first", 0)
)
.then(
  // This message is printed fourth.
  () => {sleepPrint(secondDelay)}
)
.then(
  myPrint("This message is printed second", 0)
);
```

Comment: <<The JavaScript interpreter makes two passes through code which contains chained ".then"s.>> more like the interpreter runs this code once, and during that run, setTimeout is called. SetTimeout schedules events that are processed only after the current call-stack has been entirely run (emptied).

Comment: @hugo - That's a valid way of looking at things too. I think of kicking off the secondDelay from the call stack as part of the second pass, since it happens at a much later time, after the previous promises have been resolved. But I just used setTimeout here to simulate asynchronous server calls.

Comment: @hugo - I'm not sure I understand. Do you mean that my choice of setTimeout here changes the order of the output?